# Manipulate imported component props and functions?

Tags: react-native

Currently I am using this component to list values from an Api.
https://github.com/maxkordiyak/react-native-dropdown-autocomplete/blob/master/components/Autocomplete/index.js

Everything goes fine until I try to look for a way to clear the value.
If you see the file in the link the inputValue is started in the constructor and I would like to clear that value manually from the file where I use it.

this is parte of the code (of the component) where you can see the input value :

```
import {Autocomplete, withKeyboardAwareScrollView} from "react-native-dropdown-autocomplete";

class Autocomplete extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputValue: props.initialValue || "", /* THIS IS THE ONE I NEED TO CLEAR MANUALLY*/
      loading: false,
      filteredItems: [],
    };
    this.mounted = false;
    this.timer = null;
    ...
    ...
```

Basically I use the autocomplete component like this:

```
                           <Autocomplete
                                key={1}
                                inputContainerStyle={styles.autocompleteContainer}
                                style={styles.loginFormTextInput}
                                scrollToInput={ev => scrollToInput(ev)}
                                handleSelectItem={(item, id) => this.handleSelectItem(item, id)}
                                onDropdownClose={() => onDropdownClose()}
                                onDropdownShow={() => onDropdownShow()}
                                fetchDataUrl={apiUrl}
                                placeholder={"Search..."}
                                minimumCharactersCount={2}
                                highlightText
                                valueExtractor={item => item.name + " " + item.address}
                                leftContent
                                rightTextExtractor={item => item.properties}
                            />
```

Is there a way I can get the value from the autocomplete and clear it?

Note: I do not want to "resetOnSelect" event because I need to keep the value and reset it through a button, this is a requirement.

EDIT: Direct Manipulation seems to be the way
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation#setnativeprops-to-clear-textinput-value

RE-EDIT: I posted my final solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way.

```
function my_comp = ({props}) => {
  const [ toggleInput, setInputToggle ] = useState(true);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Autocomplete
        {...props}
        key={toggleInput ? 'true' : 'false'}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {setInputToggle(!toggleInput);}}>
        <Text>Reset</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

You can use whatever the value and states to re-render the Autocomplete.
Above code will re-render the Autocomplete on Button tap and will reset the value.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in 2 simple steps:

## 1 - Set a ref to the Component:

```
<Autocomplete
    ref="refSelectOrigin"
    ...
```

## 2 - Override the value by accesing directly to the component:

```
this.refs.refSelectOrigin.setState({
    inputValue: "",
    }
)
```